# Review Audit dispute

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I will try and make this short.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/11523452) is not fit for an audit IMO.

It contains relevant code, relevant error and place where the error occurred. I even went ahead and clicked the question before pressing "Reopen" and decided it is certainly not terrible enough to be closed as "Unclear what you are asking".

Please consider removing this question from the audit queue.

I did not get banned for this, but I assume it accumulates towards a future ban if I fail another audit, so I will appreciate if this failed audit can be removed from my record.

Comment: It certainly *used* to be a bad question, and some of the close votes probably were cast at that time. But at least the final vote was cast *well after* it was transformed into a suitable-looking question, with all the information it seems one would need to answer it. Also curiously, *none* of the 5 close-voters hold so much as a bronze badge in [java]. Agreed, this is a bad audit, and probably a wrongly-closed question to boot.

Comment: I suspected that this was the case, and also I think it "helps" that the user has his account *deleted*, making this a more "suitable" audit question by the system standards...

Answer (score -2):

The question was very unclear in the first [3 revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35280682/1), which is why it was closed as "unclear". It was made clearer after it was edited, however, I still think the post should be closed - but for another reason ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it) of many duplicates).

Honestly, if I were reviewing it I wouldn't have vote to reopen. It's unlikely for this question to help anyone (OP already got an answer) and if it was reopened, I think it should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: A couple of thoughts. (1) The question was not closed while it was unclear. Granted, up to 4 people might have voted to close it at that time, but at least the 5th close vote was cast several days after the question was edited into shape. (2) The review queue should not require you to go hunting for a possible duplicate just to make a decision about whether a question should stay closed or not. That's not to say I have mixed feelings about dupe-closure—I love it and do it often. But that's far too big of a burden to put on reviewers, I think. (3) The OP's needs aren't relevant to reopening.

Comment: @CodyGray Some questions are really not worth reopened, regardless of the closure reason - that's what I feel about this one (I agree that OP's need aren't relevant, I was referring others needs. I don't think someone will come across this question just because he Googled "ArrayIndexOutOfBounds").

Comment: Having said all that, I still strongly feel that this question is very unfit to be used as an **audit**. Audits should be very clear and be used as tests for people who aren't paying any attention. If even after going into the question there is still doubt of "well... not 100% sure this should be reopened or not" then it's a terrible audit...